# get value (Image) from forum to save it in folder

Tags: php, prestashop, e-commerce

I add a logo for the Customer

the problem is I can't get the value of the image from the forum

p.s. : I want to save it to the folder

```
 public function getFormat()
    {$format = [];
        $format['id_customer'] = (new FormField())
        ->setName('id_customer')
        ->setType('hidden')
        ;
     $format['CustomerImage'] = (new FormField())
            ->setName('CustomerImage')
            ->settype('file')
            ->setLabel(
                $this->translator->trans(
                'Photo or Logo', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
                )
            )
         //->setRequired(true)
         ;}
```

[image]

Anyone can help, please!